# Is there a way to disable a particular css feature for chrome / firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-grid

Is there someway I can disable a particular CSS feature for my browser so I can view how the page will look in browsers that don't support that feature?
For instance I am using CSS grid. But I want to disable CSS grid feature in my chrome/firefox so I can see how my layout will look in browsers that don't support CSS grid?

Comment: hope this will help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports

Comment: I am using feature queries to check if the browser supports Grid and if not apply an alternate style. But as my browser supports grid I don't know if my feature queries are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery you can detect which browser is being used by the website

```
if($.browser.chrome) {
   $('#mytargetitemid').removeClass('.cssgrid')
} else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
   alert(2);
} else if ($.browser.msie) {
   alert(3);
}
```

this code removes the class tag of that item and hence css is not applied to it :-

```
$('#mytargetitemid').removeClass('.cssgrid')
```

hope this helps, revert if any confusion

Comment: I want to disable the feature from browser side. So I can test if my feature queries are working properly. For example, my current version of chrome supports grid.i have written alternate CSS as fallback if my browser is not compatible with grid it wont tottally break my site. But as my browser supports grid I don't know how to test if my feature queries are working.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can check how many version of browsers support grid layout, [compatability](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid).

in IE browser you have the option to test as per versions but I doubt we have the same option in chrome.

Comment: you could check if its possible go to - chrome://flags

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hack and not a standard, but it could help -> `@media-query` swap.
All you need to do is to swap the queries, e.g.

Wrap your original query in `@supports *not* (display: grid) {...}` as if you're targeting non-grid browsers and of course, those browsers won't understand it anyway, then allow the other codes to run.